# Actionscript3 how to get the index of object clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, indexing

I'm trying to have this hero shoot the bullet. Ex: The bullet has fire and ice type. if the hero placed is fire type then it will shoot fire bullet, if it's ice type then it will shoot ice bullet. And each bullet have each own effects and damages.

So, I've tried to get the index of hero chosen and later on the index will be used to define which bullet used by tracing (heroesArray.indexOf(heroClicked)); but the value of heroclicked is (object Hero1). so I can't use it since the array of heroesArray is [hero1,hero2]. I did splitting and joining too but it kinda messed up...

My question is how to get the String value that only contains the variable of clicked object (hero1 or hero2)? Is there any 'vocabulary' to get the variable name like getqualifiedclassname used for getting class name of an object?

Or is there any other idea to create bullet type the same as hero type without using indexOf ?

Thanks !

Here is the code :

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip
import flash.events.MouseEvent
import flash.events.Event
import flash.display.Sprite
import flash.utils.*

public class Hero {
    private var heroesArray:Array;
    private var heroContainer:Sprite = new Sprite;
    private var hero1:MovieClip = new Hero1();
    private var hero2:MovieClip = new Hero2();
    private var bulletArray:Array;
    private var bullet1:MovieClip = new Bullet1();
    private var bullet2:MovieClip = new Bullet2();
    private var moveHero:Boolean = false;
    private var movingHero:MovieClip;
    private var _money:Money =  new Money();
    private var _main:Main;
    private var _enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(_main);

    public function Hero(main:Main) 
    {   _main = main;
        heroesArray = [hero1,hero2];
        bulletArray = [bullet1,bullet2];
    }

    private function playerMoving(e:Event):void
    {
        if (moveHero == true)
        {
            movingHero.x = _main.mouseX;
            movingHero.y = _main.mouseY;
        }


    }

    private function chooseHero(e:MouseEvent):void
    {   
        var heroClicked:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

        var cost:int = _main._money.money ;
        if(cost >= 10 && moveHero == false)
        {
            _main._money.money -= 10;
            _main._money.addText(_main);

            moveHero = true;
            var heroClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(heroClicked)) as Class;
            movingHero = new heroClass(); 
            heroContainer.addChild(movingHero);
            movingHero.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, placeHero);
        }
    }

    private function placeHero(e:MouseEvent):void
    {   
        var heroClicked:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

        var heroRow:int = Math.floor(_main.mouseY/75);
        var heroCol:int = Math.floor((_main.mouseX-10)/65);

        if(heroRow>0 && heroCol>0 && heroRow<6 && heroCol<10&&
            _main.field[heroRow][heroCol]==0)

        {   
            movingHero.fireRate =75;
            movingHero.recharge = 0;
            movingHero.firing = false;
            movingHero.heroRow = heroRow;

            movingHero.x = 42+heroCol*65;
            movingHero.y = 10+heroRow*75;
            _main.field[heroRow][heroCol]=1;
            moveHero = false;
            movingHero.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, placeHero);    
        }
    }

    public function displayHero(stage:Object):void
    {   
        stage.addChild(heroContainer);

        for (var i:int = 0; i<2;i++)
            {
                stage.addChild(heroesArray[i]);
                heroesArray[i].x = 37;
                heroesArray[i].y = 80+i*70;
                heroesArray[i].width=60;
                heroesArray[i].height=55;
                heroesArray[i].buttonMode = true;
                heroesArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseHero);
                heroesArray[i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playerMoving);


            }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've pretty much got the answer right in front of you. The two heros are of classes Hero1 and Hero2, and you find the class via

```
var heroClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(heroClicked)) as Class;
```

All you need to do is compare `heroClass` to those two classes like so:

```
if(heroClass == Hero1)
{
   ...
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

**Linking hero to bullet type**

If you don't know, or don't want to learn classes (see my comment for an excellent tutorial) then you'll need a lookup table/Dictionary so that you can link bullet type to hero.

```
//Put this in your constructor after the bullet types and heroes have been declared
var bulletDict = new Dictionary();
bulletDict[hero1] = bulletTypeIce; //Note the lack of quotations around hero1 and 2
bulletDict[hero2] = bulletTypeFire;
```

So, to get the bullet type out:

```
var bulletType = bulletDict[heroClicked];
```

Comment: well, I've thought of using 'if'. but I am thinking of splitting bullet and hero into different class. so, it might be better if I pass index of hero array into the bullet array to make it same isn't it? I'm still not sure though.  I will try this if there's no other solution. thanks anyway for answering.

Comment: I would suggest very strongly that you learn how to use custom classes; it will make this issue trivial to solve. This: http://www.flashandmath.com/bridge/intro/ is the very best tutorial I've seen for custom classes. Take the time to learn that, and what it can do for you, and I you will have a much easier time with problems like this.

Comment: If you decide not to learn classes (You really need to learn classes) I've included a change to my answer for solution re: your new addition

Comment: thanks a lot for giving the references to tutorial. I've read and learnt it, but I haven't full understood it though. But at least, now I know that my class is really messed up and all the action should be from main class not done by the class itself. Thanks. Beside that, can you please explain what is new Dictionary() for? and anyway, there's an error after putting that code, Access of undefined property of bulletTypeIce and bulletTypeFire. Any idea why?

Comment: bulletTypeIce and bulletTypeFire were examples I put in there, put your own variables in there instead (the variables that you are using as ice and fire bullets)

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly, by the way what is Dictionary in actionscript? what is it for?

Comment: A Dictionary is like an array, accept, instead of using a number like this: array[1], you can use any as3 object, like this: dictionary[anyASvariable]. If this answered your question, please click the tick :)

Comment: oh I understand now. never know it before. Thanks a lot. Sure